# JavaScript for responsive (mobile first approach) dropdown menu / horizontal menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm building a responsive website with a single page layout and mobile first approach. Well, at least I'm trying but the menu has been a struggle from the beginning.

I have searched for menu snippets that are as similar to how I want the finished result and adjusted them, but so far have I only failed. I have tried so many different codes but this is what I have currently. I can kind of understand why this doesn't work but I have no more ideas. I would really need some help.

```js
  $(function () {
        var handleMatchMedia = function(md) {
            if (md.matches) {
            // window width is at least 840px
                $(".nav-toggle").click(function () {
                $(this).next("div").slideToggle(250);
                });
            } else {
            // window width is less than 840px
                $(".nav-toggle").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp(250);
                $(this).next("div").delay(360).slideToggle(250);
                });
            }
        };
        var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 840px)");

        handleMatchMedia(mq);
        mq.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
      });
```

```css
header {
  background-color: #171717;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  z-index: 2; }
  header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9e9ea1; }
  header a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: calc(1.5rem/6);
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem; }
  header ::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #171717; }
  header ::selection {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #171717; }

#nav-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: calc((1.5rem*2*12) + (1.5rem*11));
  padding: calc(1.5rem/2) 1.5rem;
  height: calc(1.5rem*2); }

.navigation .nav-toggle span {
  cursor: pointer; }

.navigation .nav-list {
  display: none; }
  .navigation .nav-list ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: calc(1.5rem/2) 0 1.5rem;
    top: calc(1.5rem*2);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #171717; }
    .navigation .nav-list ul li {
      padding: calc(1.5rem/2) 0;
      display: block; }

.navigation .nav-main {
  width: 66.66667%;
  float: left; }

@media all and (min-width: 940px) {
  .nav-main .nav-toggle {
    display: none; }
  .nav-main .nav-list {
    display: block; }
    .nav-main .nav-list ul {
      position: static;
      padding: 0; }
      .nav-main .nav-list ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 calc(1.5rem/2); }
        .nav-main .nav-list ul li:first-child {
          padding-left: 0; }
        .nav-main .nav-list ul li:last-child {
          padding-right: 0; }
  .nav-main .active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: calc(1.5rem/6);
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem; } }
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#"><span><span>B</span>rand</span> Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <nav class="nav-main left">
        <div class="nav-toggle text-center">
          <span>Menu</span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-list">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#bio">Bio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**What it does now (sometimes):**

- The dropdown "blinks"/slide up directly when clicked.
- The menu items doesn't always show up on a bigger screen.

**What I wish it would do:**

- Be a (closed) dropdown as standard but change to a horizontal menu on
  bigger screens.
- Dropdown to close when the user clicks on an 'a' jump link, outside
  the menu, or on the "menu-button".

I'm new to javascript, so please write out exactly how and where (and preferably also why, I want to learn :) )

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
Changed *< a href="#bio" target="blank">Bio< /a>* to *< a href="#bio">Bio< /a>*

Comment: if your goal is to produce a professional product you should consider Bootstrap.

Comment: @user2182349 I have never used Bootstrap so I have to look up on that for my next project (this one is almost finished now). Thank you for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other user mentioned, you can use a UI Component library like Bootstrap to handle things like this for you. But if you don't (which is fine), here we go:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/carfen/pen/eRgdbj?editors=1000)

I didn't change anything in your HTML and CSS, so we'll leave those alone. Let's focus on the JavaScript

```
$(function () {
  var breakPoint = 940;
  var $window = $(window)
  var collapseMenu = function() {
    if($window.width() < breakPoint) {
      $(".nav-list").slideToggle(250);  
    }  
  };

  $(".nav-toggle").click(collapseMenu)

  $(".nav-list a").click(collapseMenu)

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    console.log(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length);
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
      collapseMenu();
    }
  });

  var handleMatchMedia = function(md) {
    if(md.matches) {
       $(".nav-list").show();
    }
    else {
      $(".nav-list").hide();
    }
  };

  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: " + breakPoint + "px)");
  handleMatchMedia(mq);
  mq.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
});
```

**Closing the menu in mobile**

In order to close the menu when in mobile, there are a couple scenarios you wanted to tackle. But first, notice that I only attempt to toggle if I know I am in the mobile layout. I'm sure there is a more performant way of doing it, but it gets the concept across.

```
  var collapseMenu = function() {
    if($window.width() < breakPoint) {
      $(".nav-list").slideToggle(250);  
    }  
  };

  $(".nav-toggle").click(collapseMenu)

  $(".nav-list a").click(collapseMenu)

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    console.log(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length);
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
      collapseMenu();
    }
  });
```

So first we create the function that does the toggling, and then we assign that function to each scenario we want the menu to close in. The first two are pretty self explanatory. But let's go into detail for the third scenario

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  if(!$(event.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
      collapseMenu();
  }
});
```

Since we want to close the menu if they click anywhere outside of the menu, that means we need to attach an event to the entire document. That will cause the function to fire every click on the page. But we don't want to collapse the menu if the user clicks within the menu itself, so we have to check the event's target to make sure that it is not within the menu container. Only if it is outside of the the navigation container, will it collapse the menu.

**Handling resizing**

The issue you had here was that you were adding a click event every time the user resized. That is why you would see the menu show and hide in increasing amount of times as you tested more and more.

```
var handleMatchMedia = function(md) {
  if(md.matches) {
    $(".nav-list").show();
  }
  else {
    $(".nav-list").hide();
  }
};

var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: " + breakPoint + "px)");
handleMatchMedia(mq);
mq.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
```

So what I've done is change it to just show or hide based on the width of the screen. That way, it just sets the menu to the expected initial state when the user resizes past the breakpoint.

Comment: Wow Nick! You're amazing! Thank you so much :D It works exactly as I wanted except for one little thing. It doesn't only close the menu on click outside (if the menu is open) but also open if I click outside of the menu. If it possible to fix that? :)

Comment: In the document click event, just call the hide (or slideUp) jquery function instead of the slideToggle